# Library Influence.ME: Object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Tags: r, lme4

I try to detect influential cases in a glmer model (`lme4`) using the `Influence.ME` library.

I get the following error:

> Error in data.adapted[, group.var] :    object of type 'closure' is
>   not subsettable

I know what this error means, I'm trying to index a function. The problem is that I do not know how to fix it. Is it caused by the formatting of my data-matrix? Because I'm estimated a logistic regression model?

Any help is appreciated.

=====
The example code works:

```
data(school23)
model.a <- lmer(math ~ structure + SES  + (1 | school.ID), data=school23)
alt.est.a <- influence(model=model.a, group="school.ID")
```

=====
My code produces the error:

```
m1 <-glmer(outcome ~  predictor + (1 | subjects), family = binomial)
estex.m1 <- influence(m1,"subjects")
```

where outcome, predictor, and subjects all three contain a vector of 21,007 observations. (NB. Including the `data` argument in the `glmer-function` does not help)

Comment: Just to be sure did you try `data <- cbind(outcome, predictor,  subjects)` and `m1 <-glmer(outcome ~  predictor + (1 | subjects), family = binomial, data=data)`?

Comment: @abhiieor, thanks for your comment. Yes, I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. In the original model, I didn't use variable names but specified the column labels (e.g., `data[,"outcome"]`), which were incorrectly parsed in the `influence` function.